# Many requests to Google Compute Engine API in new GCP account

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Hi I have made a brand new GCP account with a single project in it.

We have not created any resources yet or credentials yet. Only the GCP account has been created.

However I do see quite a lot of requests in the API dashboard to compute engine API. All of them are anonymous hitting endpoints in GCE. Is this normal behavior and do we get billed for GCE API requests?

[GCE API requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zA0JA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is normal behavior. Google also calls your APIs to manage your services, export log files, etc.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I'm got 371,338 in the last 30 days (all from anonymous credential), and I'm getting billed $0.01 for it because of egress. If it's Google doing those requests, why is it billing me?

Comment: Because you are using their services. I prefer Google's transparency by documenting (billing) for everything.